# Css Transition hover gradient

Tags: css

I have one question about transition effect. I created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqLgu7jw/)

I want to add a transition effect for hover. But it is not working. Anyone can help me here ?

```
.h_grid_2 .gradient_c_grd_2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:384px;
    height:200px;
    z-index:1;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
    -webkit-transition: 1s all;
    transition: 1s all;
}

.h_grid_2:hover .gradient_c_grd_2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:384px;
    height:200px;
    z-index:1;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255 255, 255, 0.2));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2));
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2));
    -webkit-transition: 1s all;
    transition: 1s all;
}
```

Comment: CSS transitions do not support background images yet (and CSS gradients are considered as images, too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout my way: http://jsfiddle.net/gqLgu7jw/1/

The idea is to add another div (.gradient_c_grd_3) and use styles like these:

```
.h_grid_2:hover .gradient_c_grd_3{
    opacity: 1;
}

.h_grid_2:hover .gradient_c_grd_2 {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is right solution. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

This is impossible for now! CSS transitions do not support background images yet.

But you can play with ghe background-size and background-position:

Quoted from **[Animating CSS3 Gradients](http://www.impressivewebs.com/animating-css3-gradients/)**:

> ... since CSS3 gradients are not really properties, but are actually
>   images created by the browser, they aren’t in that list of animatable
>   properties. But that doesn’t mean you can’t animate gradients.
>
> Gradients, just like standard images, are subject to certain
>   background-related properties that are animatable. These include
>   background-size and background-position.

For some basic code-snippets and examples incorporating this idea, I suggest you have a look at the above website.